# Constructor in shared object not called in when LD_PRELOAD-ing a go executable

Tags: c, go, alpine-linux, ld-preload

There is a strange behavior around GO executable built in Alpine images where standard LD_PRELOAD feature is not working correctly.

It looks like **constructor functions are not called** by the dynamic loader!

I have an example go application (`getgoogle.go`):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://google.com/")
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
    }
}
```

And the example shared object code (`libldptest.c`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void __attribute__((constructor)) StaticConstructor(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    printf(">>> LD_PRELOADED!\n");
}
```

I am creating a debian based docker image with this Dockerfile (`gotest` image):

```
FROM golang
COPY libldptest.c hello-world.go /
RUN gcc -shared -o /libldptest.so /libldptest.c
RUN go build -gcflags='-N -l' -o /getgoogle /getgoogle.go
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/libldptest.so
```

Then running the following command:

```
$docker run -it gotest /getgoogle
>>> LD_PRELOADED!
200
```

This means the constructor works here.

But when doing the same with an alpine based docker image

```
FROM golang:1.12-alpine
RUN apk add gcc libc-dev
COPY libldptest.c hello-world.go /
RUN gcc -shared -o /libldptest.so /libldptest.c
RUN go build -gcflags='-N -l' -o /getgoogle /getgoogle.go
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/libldptest.so
```

And running the same command as above

```
$docker run -it gotest /getgoogle
200
$docker run -it gotest ls
>>> LD_PRELOADED!
bin  src
```

Meaning the static constructor was not called when running the go application! (but is was called when running `ls`)

Note that I have checked that the dynamic loader adds the library to the process space.

I'd be grateful to understand why it is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28909

Comment: This explains the problem!

Comment: I didn't really have read this, but it seems to be related to the problem...

Comment: What needs to be done is to add my constructor to the `__CTOR_LIST__` table, because it is called in Alpine loader without GO. I am looking into how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a principal problem with static constructors in the Go/Alpine environment as one can see from the comments. In short, from an ABI perspective, the requirement to call static constructors is assigned to the executable and not the loader. Go executable is no based on C runtime and it only calls the static constructors of the dependency shared objects and not `LD_PRELOAD`-ed shared objects. In case of glibc the constructors of a `LD_PRELOAD`-ed shared objects called by implementation and not by design by the loader. On musl-libc they are not.

I have made a **"hack"-ish** workaround to make existing Go apps work with a `LD_PRELOAD`-ed shared object. I am using the fact that the library is `LD_PRELOAD`-ed in this environment correctly by musl-libc and that Go is calling `pthread_create` in very 
early stage of the initialization.

I am overriding/hooking the `pthread_create` symbol in the `LD_PRELOAD`-ed shared object and uses it to call constructors.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)
{
    int (*pthread_create_original)(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"pthread_create");
    static int already_called = 0;

    if (!already_called)
    {
        already_called = 1;
        // call here your constructors
    }

    return pthread_create_original(thread,attr,start_routine,arg);
}
```

**Caveats:** this works with current Go runtime, but the assumptions on this solution is built are far from being future proof. Next Go releases can easily break it.

Answer (score 0):

Stop ignoring the first comment. If you insist on using Go's internal linker that does not link in a way that's compatible with libc use then you can't use any C code, including `LD_PRELOAD`ed C code or even features of the dynamic linker itself. As Florian (from glibc) said in the linked issue, it is not valid with glibc either and "working" only by chance there.

Even if you somehow figure out "mechanically" why your ctor isn't being called, you're still running C code in a corrupted process state and anything could go wrong. Even if you analyze everything and it seems fine, this can change entirely with next dynamic linker/libc update.

If you want to do this, use the external linker option in Go.

Comment: I guess I did not articulate the premise of my question. I am using LD_PRELOAD because I have no control over the Go application, neither of its link/compilation flags...

Comment: Well then you're stuck, without hacking the binary. The application was linked in a way that's not compatible with using `LD_PRELOAD`.